# Python Web Scrape to CSV is missing field

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to export all of my information I pulled from TripAdvisor onto a CSV that contains the name of the restaurant and its address. However in my code below, when I check the csv I exported it only puts the address collected from TripAdvisor and doesn't fill the restaurant name. A fresh set of eyes on this would be nice because I can't figure out what's wrong as of now.

Here is my code:

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#loop to move into the next pages. entries are in increments of 30 per page
for i in range(0, 30, 30):
    while i <= range:
        i = str(i)
        #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa; hence entries as variable
        url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
        r1 = requests.get(url1)
        data1 = r1.text
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
        for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
            #print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            #print link.string
            account_name = link.string
            r_address = requests.get(restaurant_url)
            r_addresstext = r_address.text
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r_addresstext, "html.parser")
            for restaurant_url in soup2.findAll('span', {'street-address'})[0]:
                #print(restaurant_url.string)
                rest_address = restaurant_url.string
                #rest_array = [account_name, rest_address]
                #print rest_array
                with open('ListingsPull-HongKong.csv', 'a') as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file)
                    writer.writerow([account_name, rest_address])
        break
```

Comment: What do you see when you print `[account_name, rest_address]`? Also what is the purpose of `while i<=range:`?

Comment: When you print that you see _[u'\nTin Lung Heen\n', u'International Commerce Centre, 1 Austin Road West, Kowloon']_ as one of the first entries. As for the while loop, I just got rid of that after running it without and the code still working successfully. @THeeren

Comment: Try removing the `\n` round the `account_name`. You could use `account_name = link.string.strip()` or similar

Comment: That worked! Thank you! @THeeren